# Lightweight Java implementation of lodash .get() function

Tags: javascript, java, android, json

I'm accessing deeply nested json objects in an Android project, and I'd like to not have to do upwards of 4 null checks to reference specific objects.

In JS, Lodash has the `.get()` function, which makes accessing those contents much more concise. Is there something similar available for Java?

edit:  FWIW, [I wrote an implementation](https://github.com/john-oleary/GetUtil/blob/master/src/GetUtil.java) of this using Reflection.  Because of the inherent performance hit of Reflection, this is probably not a good candidate for hot code paths.  Would be interested to see alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - https://javadev.github.io/underscore-java/. It's underscore.js in java with `find()`.